# NSButtonCell in NSCell-based NSTableView & Bindings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsbuttoncell

I have an `NSButtonCell` as data cell in one of my `NSTableView`'s columns. The table view is cell-based and has two columns ; one with the button cell, one with a text field cell.

The button cell's respective column's `target` and `argument` are bound to my app delegate (as the target) and to the `selectedObjects` array of an `NSArrayController` (as the argument).
Basically the same as what's outlined in [one of Apple's Technical Q&As](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1472/_index.html).

When I open the app, the table view is automatically populated. Everything works as expected. If I click a button my action method gets called just fine, and this method receives the `selectedObjects` as a parameter.

It's just not the functionality I want ; I'd like to get the object that is represented by the row of the clicked `NSButtonCell` instead of the currently selected objects (in my case this is an `NSString` as my `NSArrayController` is populated with strings).

Is it possible to get this particular object, only through bindings? Or should I, instead, set the selector of the `NSButtonCell` (the data cell) without bindings? And then get the object by using `NSTableView`'s `-clickedRow` method?

Comment: It might work to bind the argument to `arrangedObjects`. In theory, when you do that, each row would be bound to the individual object, not the array of objects, but the theory may be wrong.

Comment: Yeah I thought that too, didn't work. It works for the `NSTextFieldCell` though. Rather confusing.

Comment: If `-clickedRow` returns the correct value the way it's set up now, that might work. (I don't use array controllers for table views very much.)